# Difference between a runspace and external request in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, runspace

According to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.internal.internalcommand.commandorigin?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0#System_Management_Automation_Internal_InternalCommand_CommandOrigin

There is a runspace, and there is what they refer to as an "external request". I am wondering the difference between these two, specifically the "external requests", as I cannot find any information on what a Powershell "external request" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on the [CommandOrigin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandorigin?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) of the link you supplied takes you to a page that has descriptions for what these are:

> Internal - The command was dispatched by the msh engine as a result
>   of a dispatch request from an already running command.
>
> Runspace - The command was submitted via a runspace.